# Postgres pass refcursor output of a procedure to another procedure

Tags: postgresql

I have this stored procedure `T1` which returns a `refcursor`.

```
create procedure t1(inout rr refcursor)
as $$
begin
open rr for select 'receiving it';
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Another stored procedure `t_main` calls `T1` and it needs to return the same `refcursor` result set of `T1`.

```
create or replace procedure t_main(inout rc refcursor)
as
$$
declare
rc_in refcursor;
begin
call t1(rc_in);
rc := rc_in;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

The part `rc := rc_in;` is not passing the refcursor `rc_in` to `rc`. When I execute `t_main`, I get error saying `cursor 'rc' does not exist`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is as below

```
create or replace procedure t_main(inout rc refcursor)
as
$$
begin
call t1(rc );
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

Using the same `refcursor` parameter of the main procedure in the dependent procedure solved the issue.